# Mu-editor installation failed

Tags: command-line, software-installation, pip, text-editor

I tried to install Mu-editor from the terminal with `pip install mu-editor`. It downloaded everything, and at the end of installation I got this error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3.8 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-zh4eovyq/pygame/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-zh4eovyq/pygame/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-zh4eovyq/pygame/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-zh4eovyq/pygame/
    Complete output (12 lines):

    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using UNIX configuration...

    /bin/sh: 1: sdl-config: not found
    /bin/sh: 1: sdl-config: not found
    /bin/sh: 1: sdl-config: not found

    Hunting dependencies...
    WARNING: "sdl-config" failed!
    Unable to run "sdl-config". Please make sure a development version of SDL is installed.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1):

These commands worked for me. Virtual environment on python3.6

```
python3  -m venv mu
source ~/myvenev/mu/bin/activate
sudo pip3 install mu-editor
```

Output:

```
Successfully installed Pillow-8.1.2 PyQt5-sip-12.8.1 PyQtChart-5.14.0 appdirs-1.4.4 colorzero-1.1 
                       cycler-0.10.0 gpiozero-1.5.1 guizero-1.1.1 ipykernel-5.5.0 jupyter-client-6.1.12
                       jupyter-core-4.7.1 kiwisolver-1.3.1 matplotlib-2.2.2 mu-editor-1.0.3 
                       nudatus-0.0.5 numpy-1.19.5 pgzero-1.2 pigpio-1.78 pycodestyle-2.4.0 
                       pyflakes-2.0.0 pygame-1.9.6 pyparsing-2.4.7 pyqt5-5.14.1 pyserial-3.4 
                       pytz-2021.1 qscintilla-2.11.4 qtconsole-4.3.1 semver-2.13.0 tornado-6.1
```

---

```
(mu) masua@w2l-pc:~/0l2p0/Python/ide/mu$  mu-editor
Registrando en /home/masua/.cache/mu/log/mu.log
QApplication: invalid style override 'gtk' passed, ignoring it.
    Available styles: Windows, Fusion
Gtk-Message: 09:39:53.450: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Gtk-Message: 09:40:11.517: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Gtk-Message: 09:47:19.852: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
QObject::killTimer: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running
Abortado (`core' generado)
(mu) masua@w2l-pc:~/0l2p0/Python/ide/mu$ [IPKernelApp] WARNING | Parent appears to have exited, shutting down.
^C
(mu) masua@w2l-pc:~/0l2p0/Python/ide/mu$
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: 
You also appear to have a missing dependency on SDL-devel; but the first error is python3.8 related afik.

`sudo apt install libsdl2-dev` may also be needed..

Original reply:
It appears to be [a python 3.8 incompatibility](https://github.com/mu-editor/mu/issues/999):
You should be able to `sudo apt install python3.7` and then create a virtualenv for python37 like this:

```
$ virtualenv --python=`which python3.7` venv37
$ source venv37/bin/activate
```

(not tested by me, but should work.. based on a reply I used [here](https://github.com/mu-editor/mu/issues/999#issuecomment-624033473))